# GUI Button for all screen resolutions

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, screen-orientation, unityscript

I am using OnGUI Buttons on a car game and attached forward and backward buttons on it. But they keep on adjusting on all screens badly.

I have tried various online solutions, but failed. I am using this:

```
GUI.RepeatButton (new Rect (Screen.width - 780, Screen.height - 130, 120, 120), LeftBtnTexture, TransparentStyle)
```

I know this is wrong, what will be alternative width and height setting for all screens. :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Screen.dpi - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html

It will allow you to specify button size in inches. But be aware that dpi could be unavailable (equals zero) or maybe even incorrect, therefore you should do some sanity check. For example:

```
public float sizeInInches = 0.5;
float dpi = Screen.dpi;
if (dpi < 25 || dpi > 800) {
    dpi = 150;
}
float sizeInPx = sizeInInches * dpi;
```

As an alternative for some cases, you may want to set GUI element size in percent of screen dimensions, like `sizeInPx = Screen.width * 0.1;`